# Rewriting the URL using .htaccess blocking the adsense ads

Tags: .htaccess, adsense

I am rewriting the URL subdomain.domain.com/result.php?domain=example.com using .htaccess
When I hit the above URL google AdSense ads show on the web page but when I rewrite the URL to subdomain.domain.com/example.com google Adsense ads stops showing on the page. My URL and subdomain are verified on AdSense. I am not getting what is happening here. Why ads are being blocked. Why it is not showing. Below is the .htaccess code I am using:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ pages.php?page=$1 [L] 
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^top/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ top.php?p=$1 [L] 
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$  result.php?domain=$1 [L] 
    </IfModule>
```

Please let me know what can I update in the code.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this.. I am searching for the solution desperately.

Comment: could you please do let us know sample urls too for better understanding thank you.